# How to assign cell value from a for loop variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code that creates an array from a single cell of text, based on the spaces in the cell. Then it is supposed to cycle through each array value and see which dictionary key value it is equivalent.

After that, the code goes to a worksheet, copies data based on the active cell and pastes into a new worksheet. Everything is working, except I would like to paste the dictionary key with the data as well. I have tried assigning a variable with the key value and setting the range to the key value.

I have tested and if I write: selection.value = 500, 500 is entered into the selection range. Would love any help/pointers. Thanks!

```
Sub Macro2()

'Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl p

Dim dict As Object
Dim search As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim interval_array As Variant
Dim interval As String
Dim paste As Range

Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

dict.Add Key:=500, Item:=1
dict.Add Key:=800, Item:=2
dict.Add Key:=1000, Item:=3
dict.Add Key:=2000, Item:=4
dict.Add Key:=3000, Item:=5
dict.Add Key:=4000, Item:=6
dict.Add Key:=5000, Item:=7
dict.Add Key:=6000, Item:=8
dict.Add Key:=7000, Item:=9
dict.Add Key:=8000, Item:=10
dict.Add Key:=9000, Item:=11
dict.Add Key:=10000, Item:=12
dict.Add Key:=12000, Item:=13
dict.Add Key:=14000, Item:=14
dict.Add Key:=16000, Item:=15
dict.Add Key:=18000, Item:=16
dict.Add Key:=20000, Item:=17
dict.Add Key:=22000, Item:=18
dict.Add Key:=24000, Item:=19
dict.Add Key:=26000, Item:=20
dict.Add Key:=28000, Item:=21
dict.Add Key:=30000, Item:=22
dict.Add Key:=32000, Item:=23

search = ActiveCell.Value
interval_array = Split(search, " ")

ActiveCell.Offset(2).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("data_table").Activate
ActiveSheet.paste
ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Offset(0, 2).Select

For Each word In interval_array
    For Each Key In dict
        'MsgBox (word)
        'MsgBox (key)
        If Key = word Then
            'interval = word.Value
             Selection.Value = word.Text
        Else
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the outcome you are looking for in case of 500 ? should it return 1?

Comment: So regardless of if the key is 500, 1000, 10000, etc.. its' value should be pasted two columns to the right of the selection area located in "Data_Table". The logic being tested against key is to find which key is located in the array "interval_array"

Answer (score 0):

To use the `Dictionary` object capabilities within VBA:

1. To check if any of the array `interval_array` is found in the `dict` object, you can use:

   `If dict.exists(CLng(word)) Then`
2. To retrieve the `Item` from `dict` you can use:

   `Selection.Value = dict(CLng(word))`